# Need to pass array to route and controller

Tags: laravel, routes

I need to pass array to route and controller from view.

I get the error:

> Missing required parameters for `[Route: actBook] [URI: bookfromindex/actBook/{id}/{array}]`.

I have my route defined as:

```
Route::get('/bookfromindex/actBook/{id}/{array}', 'BookController@actBook')->name('actBook');
```

My controller function is defined as:

```
public function actBook(Request $request, $id, $array){
```

And I call this route in my view using:

```
<a href="{{ route('actBook', $room->id, $array) }}" class="btn btn-default">დაჯავშნა</a>
```

How do I prevent this error?

Comment: could you show piece of code?

Comment: `Route::get('/bookfromindex/actBook/{id}/{array}', 'BookController@actBook')->name('actBook');`

Comment: Controller: `public function actBook(Request $request, $id, $array){`

Comment: view: `<a href="{{ route('actBook', $room->id, $array) }}" class="btn btn-default">დაჯავშნა</a>`

Comment: @GenoMumladze There is an edit function on questions, please edit your question next time to include the code instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change -

```
<a href="{{ route('actBook', $room->id, $array) }}" class="btn btn-default">დაჯავშნა</a>
```

to -

```
<a href="{{ route('actBook', $room->id, serialize($array)) }}" class="btn btn-default">დაჯავშნა</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to serialize your array then you can pass into the parameter

Example :

```
{{  $serializeArray = serialize($array) }} 
<a href="{{ route('actBook', $room->id, $serializeArray) }}" class="btn btn-default">
```

Controller :

```
public function actBook(Request $request, $id, $array){
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/bookfromindex/actBook/{id}/{array}', 'BookController@actBook')->name('actBook');
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: you are just echoing the result of that serialization right on the page there ... `{{ }}` is for echoing

Answer (score 1):

Just use `serialize($array);`
Then pass this array to the route.