# Laravel pass array in route

Tags: php, laravel

Hello all I have code:

```
{{ route('data', ['min' => 12, 'max' => 123, 'week' => 1, 'month' => 123]) }}
```

In routes:

```
Route::get('/data/{array?}', 'ExtController@get')->name('data');
```

In ExtController:

```
class GanttController extends Controller
{  

public function get($array = [], 
Request $request){
   $min = $array['min'];
   $max= $array['max'];
   $week = $array['week'];
   $month = $array['month'];
}
```

But this is not working, I not get params in array. How I can get params in controller?

I tryeid do with function: `serialize`, but I get error: `missing required params of the route.` Becuase I have `?` in route.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to pass array to route and controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695202/need-to-pass-array-to-route-and-controller)

Comment: I tried do serialize, I get error: `missing required params..`

Comment: @Jadasdas where does you are getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do as you did:

```
{{ route('data', ['min' => 12, 'max' => 123, 'week' => 1, 'month' => 123]) }}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/data', 'ExtController@get')->name('data');
```

Controller:

```
class GanttController extends Controller
{  
    public function get(Request $request){
       $min = $request->get('min');
       $max= $request->get('max');
       $week = $request->get('week');
       $month = $request->get('month');
    }
}
```

Your data will be passed as `$_GET` parameters - `/data?min=12&max=123&week=1&month=123`

Answer (score 0):

First of you need to serialize the array:

```
{{ route('data', serialize(['min' => 12, 'max' => 123, 'week' => 1, 'month' => 123])) }}
```

Then you can pass it :

```
Route::get('/data/{array?}', 'ExtController@get')->name('data');
```

Comment: `Missing required parameters for [Route: data] [URI: api/data/{array?}]` I have: `route('data', serialize(['min' => request()->get('min'), 'max' => request()->get('max'), 'week' => request()->get('week'), 'month' => request()->get('month')]))`

Comment: I do not see any required param, array its optional in that route .

Comment: dfauq how can you use request in front end, use javascript to get the data from the form. REQUEST ITS FOR BACKEND

Comment: I need pass params on route. I load /data from javascript.

Comment: `gantt.load("{{ route('data', serialize(['min' => request()->get('min'), 'max' => request()->get('max'), 'week' => request()->get('week'), 'month' => request()->get('month')])) }}");`

Answer (score 0):

> You write your code in the wrong controller.

Your code must be like:

```
class ExtController extends Controller
{  

public function get()
{
   // your code
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data as query string parameters.

Define your route as

```
Route::get('/data', 'ExtController@get')->name('data');
```

in your view

```
{{ route('data', ['min' => 12, 'max' => 123, 'week' => 1, 'month' => 123]) }}
```

and in your controller

```
class GanttController extends Controller
{  
    public function get(Request $request){
       $min = $request->get('min');
       $max= $request->get('max');
       $week = $request->get('week');
       $month = $request->get('month');
    }
}
```