# Laravel, only first element of array passed to route is readable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

From a blade template I want to pass an array with a variable amount of values to a route, as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916482/laravel-pass-array-in-route).

However when I do this I can only ever access the first value in the array I pass to the route.

This is how I call the route in the blade template:

```
{{ route('stats.downloads', ['stat_kind' => 'files_size', 'group_by' => 'week', 'start' => '2020-11-01', 'end' => '2020-11-10']) }}
```

this is my route from `web.php`:

```
Route::get('stats/downloads', 'StatsController@view_stats_downloads')->name('stats.downloads');
```

and my controller:

```
public function view_stats_downloads(Request $request){
    // get the input parameters
    $group_by = $request->get('group_by');
    $stat_kind = $request->get('stat_kind');
    $company = $request->get('group_by');
    $user = $request->get('user');
    $start = $request->get('start');
    $end = $request->get('end');
    
    ...
```

The problem is, that I can only ever access the first value of the array I pass to the controller (`stat_kind` in this case). It doesn't natter in which order I call the `get()` function either.

What can I do to fix this?

I'm running laravel 5

Comment: output of `dd($request->all());` ? and what tis your expected output?

Comment: @sta 
array:4 [▼
  "stat_kind" => "files_size"
  "amp;group_by" => "week"
  "amp;start" => "2020-11-01"
  "amp;end" => "2020-11-10/"
]

Comment: @sta thank you for showing me the dd() helper, that will be usefull in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the curly braces, `{{ }}`, to `{!! !!}` where you are calling the `route` helper.

The `&` is being encoded to `&amp;` so only the first query string parameter that you are sending does not have a `&` in front of it so it is named correctly. The others are named with the `amp;`, the part after the `&` in the encoded ampersand.