# Pass array with laravel route

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-route

**My Route**

```
Route::get('complete/{purchase_id}/{failed_purchases?}', 'Controller@success');
```

**My Controller**

```
$failed_purchases = [];
for($i=0 ; $i < 2; $i++){
    $failed_purchases[] = [
        'reason' => "failed $i"
    ];
}


return redirect()->route('customer.purchase.success-purchase', [
    'purchase_id' => 10,
    'failed_purchases' => json_encode($failed_purchases)
]);
```

I need to pass an array with the route, when i try this code but i got an error `Missing required parameters for [Route`.

I also tried `serialize()`.
How to solve this ?

Comment: why don't you use post to pass array

Comment: Are you use ajax or using href?

Comment: @VinayKaklotar Its not a form submit. I redirect to a route using controller

Comment: It is your answer of question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47696176/8544723

Comment: I have a solution, dont pass the `wildcard`. I mean just remove the `wildcard from route and controller funciton`. after that, `get data from request`.

Comment: Append `->with('failed_purchases' => $failed_purchases);` after `route()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about better solution. but hope this will solve your problem.

route will be ->

```
Route::get('complete/{purchase_id}', 'Controller@success');
// it will pass the array as a querystring. and then you can get from request input.
```

controller will be ->

```
function success(Request $request, $purchase_id) {
    // do your stuff
    $failed_purchases = $request->input('failed_purchases');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you want to interpolet the value of `$i` in the string "failed $i" you must wrap the name of the variable in curly brace like bellow

```
$failed_purchases = [];
for($i=0 ; $i < 2; $i++){
    $failed_purchases[] = [
        'reason' => "failed {$i}"
    ];
}
```

And after the loop the value of `$failed_purchases` I presume will be equal to

```
$failed_purchases = [
    [
        "reason" => "failed 0"
    ],
    [
        "reason" => "failed 1"
    ],
]
```

and after you use json_encode passing the value of `$failed_purchases` it will return a string equal to

> [{"reason":"failed 0"},{"reason":"failed 1"}]

which have many double quote in it and to use that value as part in your URL you must escape it using function like `urlencode`

```
$failed_purchases_string = json_encode($failed_purchases);
$failed_purchases_string_encode = urlencode($failed_purchases_string);
```

which will be equal to some thing like this

> %5B%7B%22reason%22%3A%22failed+0%22%7D%2C%7B%22reason%22%3A%22failed+1%22%7D%5D

And at this step it can be use as parameter into the `route` method
There is one limitation which is the maximum length of a URL which mustn't exceed **2048 characters**

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good except one thing. Just make sure you have provided `failed_purchases` parameter with some default value in Controller because you have specified this parameter as optional. So your Controller action should be something like:

```
function success(Request $request, $purchase_id, $failed_purchases=null){
    //Your Code
}
```