# Laravel - pass array variable to route

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, routes, laravel-livewire

I need to pass array variable to my route, so on the next page I could use that array for project purposes.
This is my `dd` array:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "Proizvod 1"
    "description" => "Opis proizvoda 1"
    "price" => "3.20"
    "active" => 1
    "action" => 0
    "created_at" => "2021-04-13 18:22:54"
    "updated_at" => "2021-04-13 18:22:54"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "category_id" => 1
    "thumbnail" => null
    "media" => []
  ],
  1 => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "title" => "Proizvod 2"
    "description" => "Opis proizvoda 2"
    "price" => "3.20"
    "active" => 1
    "action" => 0
    "created_at" => "2021-04-13 18:22:54"
    "updated_at" => "2021-04-13 18:22:54"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "category_id" => 1
    "thumbnail" => null
    "media" => []
  ]
]
```

And this is how I tried to pass array to route:

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-block pt-2 pb-2" href="{{ route('invoice', array('orders' => $cartProducts)) }}">Nastavite<i class="feather-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

But it's showing me error:

````
Array to string conversion```

How can I do this? Is there any other way to pass this?
````

Comment: Route variable can not be array. You can send every attribute as own variable or pass it in POST form param (as json).
But I think you are doing something wrong. Try assing only IDs and then select then from DB.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695202/need-to-pass-array-to-route-and-controller) helpful?